# N'th derivative with chain rule

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, summation

I am trying to find a general form of the chain rule for higher derivatives, using the general Leibniz rule I got to the following formula. However it doesn't seem to work. I suspect it has something to do with the $n-1$ but I am unsure.
$$D^{\left(n\right)}\left(f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {n-1}{k}D^{\left(k+1\right)}g\left(x\right)D^{(n-k)}\left(f'\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)$$
(Where $D^{\left(n\right)}f(x)$ is the $n$'th derivative of $f(x)$)
The way I derived this is by using $\left(f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)^{\prime}=g^\prime(x)f^\prime(g(x))$ and then applying Leibniz rule on this for higher derivatives.

EDIT- I have managed to proof that the following formula works. Can it be proofed it is equivalent to Faà di Bruno's formula?.
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom {n-1}{k}D^{\left(n-k\right)}g\left(x\right)D^{\left(k\right)}\left(f'\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: A more usual notation for the $n$th derivative of $f(x)$ is $f^{(n)}(x)$.  I would typically interpret $(f(x))^n$ as $f(x)$ raised to the $n$th power.  Given the ambiguity, I might prefer $D^n$ or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

This is the [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}f(g(x))&=\sum\frac{n!}{m_1!1!^{m_1}m_22!^{m_2}\cdots m_nn!^{m_n}}f^{(m_1+\ldots+m_n)}(g(x))\prod_{i=1}^ng^{(i)}(x)^{m_i},\\
&=\sum\frac{n!}{m_1!\cdots m_n!}f^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{g^{(i)}(x)^{m_i}}{i!},
\end{align*}
where the sum is taken over $n$-tuples of nonnegative integers $(m_1,\cdots,m_n)$ such that:
$$1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n.$$

Answer (score 0):

I think you messed up something. You cannot apply the product rule as you did it.
Think about that. Take a look at small n.

What you are looking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula